# Best practices for parametrized Coq libraries

Tags: coq

I'm writing a library in Coq that depends on user-supplied type parameters.  One central part is a construction along the lines of

```
Require Import Ascii.
Require Import String.
Parameter UserType : Set. (* <<- placeholder for this example *)
Parameter UserToString : UserType -> string.

Inductive Tag : Set := TBool | TNat | TUser | TList : Tag -> Tag | TSum : Tag -> Tag -> Tag.
Fixpoint decodeT (t : Tag) : Set :=
  match t with
  | TBool => bool
  | TNat => nat
  | TUser => UserType (* <<- needed here *)
  | TList t' => list (decodeT t')
  | TSum l r => sum (decodeT l) (decodeT r)
  end.
(* ...etc..., including: *)
Definition tostring (t : Tag) (v : decodeT t) : string := (* match t with ... end *) "dummy".
(* and other stuff *)
```

so I can't avoid those `Parameter`s in some form.  The whole library is split across multiple files, and because of the size it would be pretty uncomfortable to put everything in one file.

There's a top-level wrapper that exports all sub-modules.  Ideally, I'd like to pass the parameters *once* when importing the library, and then this wrapper can do some magic to propagate them to all sub-modules, so that afterwards I don't have to worry about it anymore.

I've looked into various approaches, but nothing worked so far.

If I wrap the file contents in `Section`s, then the `Parameter`s become extra arguments only on the definitions that use them, and then I have to manually splice them in everywhere when using the library's functions from outside.

If I don't wrap them in a `Section`, they are module parameters but I can't find a way to actually provide the value.  (All forms of `with Definition` seem to require a module signature / `Module Type`?  Duplicating all names & types to make an explicit signature would be prohibitively redundant, so maybe there *is* a way to make it work, but I couldn't find it. The documentation is also rather unhelpful...)  Variations like using `Context` instead seem to have the same problem, as far as I tested things.

I'm happy to make a `Module Type UserDefs` (or typeclass, or whatever) that combines all the user definitions in a single value.  I just don't know how to actually get it into the submodules.

So how do I do it?  What needs to happen inside that sample file above, and what needs to happen on the outside, so that I can pass the definitions in *once* and then get a fully configured library to `Import`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> then I have to manually splice them in everywhere when using the library's functions from outside.

This is typically addressed by a mix of implicit parameters and type classes.

Declare a class for user-provided parameters.

```
Class UserParams : Type :=
  { UserType : Set
  ; UserToString : UserType -> string
  }.

(* Make sure UserType and UserToString have UserParams as a maximally inserted implicit *)
```

Then in your library open sections parameterized by instances of that class:

```
Require Import Ascii.
Require Import String.

Section MyLib.
Context {userParams : UserParams}.  (* Context generalizes Variable and allows you to set implicitness *)

Inductive Tag : Set := TBool | TNat | TUser | TList : Tag -> Tag | TSum : Tag -> Tag -> Tag.
Fixpoint decodeT (t : Tag) : Set :=
  match t with
  | TBool => bool
  | TNat => nat
  | TUser => UserType (* <<- needed here *)
  | TList t' => list (decodeT t')
  | TSum l r => sum (decodeT l) (decodeT r)
  end.
(* ...etc..., including: *)
Definition tostring (t : Tag) (v : decodeT t) : string := (* match t with ... end *) "dummy".
(* and other stuff *)

End MyLib.
```

Then users instantiate the class

```
Require Import MyLib.

Instance myParams : UserParams :=
  {| UserType := ...
   ; UserToString := ... |}.
```

And then your library functions will automatically be instantiated when you use them.